# Show the remote site page(standard) on VF Page.I have used the metadata API for my page

Tags: outputlink, remote-site-settings

I want to show the remote site setting creation page on a VF Page. So i used :

```
<apex:outputLink onclick="window.open('https://ap4.salesforce.com/0rp/e?retURL=%2F0rp%3Fspl1%3D1%26setupid%3DSecurityRemoteProxy%26retURL%3D%252Fui%252Fsetup%252FSetup%253Fsetupid%253DSecurity',' menubar=0, resizable=0,dependent=0,status=0,width=300,height=200,left=10,top=10')">Remote site Setup</apex:outputLink> '
```

This redirects to remote site setting page. After filling the information when i clicked on save it doesn't redirect to my vf page. I used my vf page name in return url but its don't help me.

Any inputs?